# DNS сервера

Tags: dns

И так докатился до DNS, ни когда раньше не работал\не слышал и не видел.У меня есть 5доменов и еще с 10поддоменов.Есть машина, соответственно к ней нужно подцепить эти домены, как более корректно такое провернуть. Сейчас просто весят домены подцепленные к IP. А хотелось бы все по человечески, подцепить к домен к нейм серверам и на самой машине уже просто раздавать домены\поддомены. Можно ли такое организовать? Дайте пожалуйста пару ссылок.ОС Debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Организовать можно. Приблизительно так: 1. Поднять DNS-сервер (https://www.google.ru/#lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+dns+debian&tbs=lr:lang_1ru) 2. "Подцепить" (как вы сказали) домены и поддомены, т.е. сделать прописи нужных вам имён и адресов.Надеюсь информации хватит? Не хватит - спрашивайте: skype - danildan75work, icq 345458854